# Why user_pass column in wp_users table is varchar(64)

Tags: database, customization

while working on a project, I found that "user_pass" column in "wp_users" table is varchar(64). WordPress always stores user password in md5 which is a 32 char ASCII string. So why not store it in char(32) with ascii collation. I am asking because I am working on a table that stores user password. Is there any other advantage of using varchar(64).

Comment: I don't think that WordPress uses md5. It uses [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

Comment: phpass is a hashing framework which supports different hashing algorithms, md5 is one of them. However, it is true that WordPress no more uses md5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of different encrypted algorithm. Sometimes users will override the MD5, which is the default algorithm, and add their own, which might need a little longer length to store the password.

Take a look at the Q&A's »[What data type to use for hashed password field and what length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247304/what-data-type-to-use-for-hashed-password-field-and-what-length)«, having detailed information about hashes and their length, at Stackoverflow for reference.